# Boostrap modal form with 2 submit buttons and save in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a form on a modal. I have a form with 2 buttons: accept and reject. 
If the user clicks on accept there is an update in that database, if the user clicks on reject there is another update. 
I need to retain a certain value from database before, so I am making a select. 
The problem is that I don't know how to make an insert in database using javascript (I know it is possible with jquery/ajax but how to call 
it in the button?).

Here is my code:
[image: the modal]

**Here is the Javascript function to insert in database that doesn't work**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicked1() {
    //update candidate_jobs SET is_hired='1' WHERE candidate_id=$userId and applied_to=$row["job_id"];

   var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection"),
   recordSet = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"),
   connectionString = '';

   connection.Open(connectionString);
   recordSet.Open(
   "update candidate_jobs SET is_hired='1' WHERE candidate_id=".$userId." and applied_to=".$row["job_id"]."";,
   connection);

   recordSet.close; 
   connection.close;

   alert('You accepted the offer');
}

   function clicked2() {
   //idem clicked1 but change the is_hired value to be inserted in the database
   alert('You rejected the offer');
   }
</script>
```

Can it be done using Jquery and Ajax? How? 
What it wrong with the code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The concatenated sql string is prone to sql injection attacks (although obviously anyone viewing the page source can do whatever they like to the database anyway) - parameterization is the solution here and we need to use an  IDENTITY or GUID.

Here is a list of possible issues:

1) The code will only ever run in IE browsers
2) You may need to download and install the COM components - ADO 
3) You may need to run IE as an Administrator
4) You may need to open all sorts of security loopholes in IE (ActiveX controls, safe for scripting etc)

If you enable script debugging on the browser you'll get more info on the actual issue.
hope it helps you.